# How to deploy from sandbox to production with visual studio code?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, deployment, visualstudiocode

I have read all documentation and don't fully understand how to move code (apex classes, visualforce pages) to production from a sandbox.

Can someone give a full process user guide how to do that?

In Eclipse I just authorize a sandbox, then select apex classes and press deploy to Production. And after authorization runs all test and code successfully moves to production system.

I'm confusing in scratch orgs and etc.

For now, I create a project with manifest, authorized in sandbox, and retrieved metadata in manifest. What's the next steps?

Answer (score 2):

I think the first important distinction to make when using VSCode, and consequently the underlying SFDX CLI, is if you are doing source driven development, org driven development, or change set driven development.

Have a look at the following Trailhead Trail and a specific module:

- Trial - [Determine Which Application Lifecycle Management Model Is Right for You](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/determine-which-application-lifecycle-management-model-is-right-for-you)
- Module - [Org Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/org-development-model)

The last module includes a step by step guide to [Test and Deploy changes](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/org-development-model/test-and-deploy-changes) between orgs.

Essentially, you build up the metadata you want to deploy into a local package and deploy it via the metadata api.

There is also the VSCode specific version of this in [Org Development Model with VS Code](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model)